# Filter on Multiple values for same column using Rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

Is it possible to filter using SharePoint REST api in sharepoint to Filter on Multiple values for same column?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**.

You can use logical operators like AND, OR to apply multiple filters on same column.

Example:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=Title&$filter=(Title eq 'ABC') or (Title eq 'XYZ')
```

Comment: Hi @kumar, have you tried this? is it working for you?